# has_manyのクラスのインスタンスをRSpecで呼び出す

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, rspec

Railsで`Company`クラスが`PastData`を`has_many`で持つ関係において
下記のようなコードを書いたのですが

```
describe Company do
  describe "exmaple test" do
    let(:company){ Company.create }
    context "fooが10の時" do
      let(:past_data){ company.past_data.build(foo: 10) }
      it "barは20" do
        expect(company.past_data_bar).to eq(20)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

#### app/models/company.rb

```
def past_data_bar
  past_data.bar
end
```

以下のように `NoMethodError`になってしまいます。

```
NoMethodError:
       undefined method `bar' for nil:NilClass
```

`company.past_data`が`nil`になっているのが原因なのはわかるのですが、解決方法がわかりませんでした。

`company.past_data.bar`と呼び出していますが、実際のコードでは`Company`クラスの内部メソッドで`past_data`を呼び出しています。

RSpecで`has_many`の関係にあるクラスを呼び出しているメソッドのテストはどのように書けば良いのでしょうか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

company.past_dataにすると、letで宣言したオブジェクトが呼ばれないので、expectの中はpast_dataだけにしてみてください。

```
describe Company do
  describe "exmaple test" do
    let(:company){ Company.create }
    context "fooが10の時" do
      let(:past_data){ company.past_data.build(foo: 10) }
      it "barは20" do
        expect(past_data.bar).to eq(20)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

EDIT:

コメントの内容を勘案するとこうなりそうです。

```
describe Company do
  describe "exmaple test" do
    let(:company){ Company.create }
    context "fooが10の時" do
      let!(:past_data){ company.past_data.build(foo: 10) }
      it "barは20" do
        expect(past_data_bar).to eq(20)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

letだとbeforeやitの中でpast_dataが呼び出されるまでletのブロックは実行されません。
let!にすると、テストの実行前に必ずブロックが呼び出されるようになります。

詳しくはこの記事を読んでみてください。

[遅延評価される let と事前に実行される let!](http://qiita.com/jnchito/items/42193d066bd61c740612#%E9%81%85%E5%BB%B6%E8%A9%95%E4%BE%A1%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B-let-%E3%81%A8%E4%BA%8B%E5%89%8D%E3%81%AB%E5%AE%9F%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B-let)

Comment: 回答有難うございます。ただ、`past_data`はCompanyクラスの内部で呼ばれているため、Companyのインスタンスにpast_dataのインスタンスをひもづける必要があるんです。コード部分に反映させていませんでしたので質問を修正しておきます。

Comment: `expect(past_data.bar)` ではなく `expect(past_data_bar)` だったんですね。ちょっと見落としていました。回答を編集したので確認してみてください。

Comment: なるほど、`let`と`let!`の違いを曖昧なままにしててよくわかってなかったんですがこういう時に必要だったんですね。ありがとうございます。